# Resharper/Nunit AssertionException was unhandled by user code

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nunit, resharper

I am trying to set up unit testing in a solution with Visual Studio Enterprise 2015 and Resharper Ultimate 2015.2.

I created a new unit test project in the solution and used NuGet to install Nunit 2.6.4.

Debugging a unit test through Resharper throws an AssertionException.  I expected it to catch the exception and report it.

For example:

```
[TestFixture]
class AssertTest
{
    [Test]
    public void IsTrue()
    {
        Assert.True(false);
    }
}
```

Is there additional configuration that needs to be done to properly integrate Resharper and Nunit?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you need the "Unit Test Session" from Resharper.
[Get it](https://www.jetbrains.com/dotcover/help/Reference__Windows__Unit_Test_Sessions.html) by CTRL+ALT+R.
From there you can right click and debug your unit tests

On second reading of your question I wonder if the scenario you're describing isn't exactly as expected? In your test you want to assert something to be TRUE. 
If it is, jolly-good -> continue. If it isn't, then you'd wanna know, hence the ASSERTIONException.

My point is, Tests should tell you if something is not as expected. And `Assert.True(False)` is doing just that.

If you wanna log, you could surround your assertions with `try-catch`, log the exception and just `throw` it. You should have the test fail, if something is not as expected.

Hope this was helpful.